# Entropy increase or decrease in an reaction

Tags: metabolism, cellular-respiration, thermodynamics

My question is how would you tell if the product of an reaction has more or less entropy than the reactants?

For example, in glycolysis, when glyceraldehyde-3-phosphate becomes 1-3 bisphosphoglycerate, BPG has less free energy and more entropy than G3P. Anyone able to give me a rundown as to how you would know? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The way you have formulated your question contains a major error. You can talk about the change in free energy or entropy in an overall chemical reaction, and entropy is not an intrinsic feature of a molecule but of the system as a whole. That said, an answer to your question on meauring entropy can be found on [SE Chemistry, here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/42066/is-there-a-way-to-experimentally-measure-entropy)..

Comment: @David I understand that, however the question was phrased like that on a test, as in which molecule (product) has a higher entropy than their reactants, in a chemical reaction. I know the entropy in terms of a system, but was just wondering if anything applies to a specific molecule. Thanks though.

Comment: I must say that in biochemistry the emphasis is on the [free energy change of reactions](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK22584/). I am not sure, but imagine that there is generally considered to be no change in entropy of the molecules, unless one is considering the environment (hydrophobic or hydrophilic) or whether a polymeric chain is ordered or not (as [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK22567/#A167)).